# How to get the all key names which is in the plist in to an array

Tags: iphone, ios, plist

I am new to iPhone.  I have a small doubt that is I have a plist looks like this

```
key               Type        Value
Genesis           Array       (50items)
Exodus            Array       (40items)
Leviticus         Array       (30items)
Numbers           Array       (20items)
```

My doubt is how can I get these all (key) names in to one array?  That is, I want an array with names of Genesis,Exodus,Leviticus,Numbers.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at [allKeys](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/nsdictionary_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSDictionary/allKeys); this returns all keys contained in the [NSDictionary](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/nsdictionary_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

```
NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] bundlePath];
NSString *finalPath = [path stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"file.plist"];
NSDictionary *dict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:finalPath];
NSArray *keys=[dict allKeys];
```

One note, the array returned by allKeys could not reflect the order of the keys in the plist, if you want to sort by keys you need to sort the `keys` array using some [comparator](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSArray_Class/NSArray.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSArray/sortedArrayUsingComparator%3a).

Answer (score 0):

```
NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource: @"yourPlist" ofType: @"plist"]; 
NSDictionary dict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile: path];
NSArray *myarray = [dict allKeys];
//NSArray *myarray = [dict allValues];//if Values Required the use allValues...
```